# "Agreements not confirmed." in customer registration

Tags: magento-1.9, registration, billing-agreements, germany

I try to add an agreement checkbox to the customer registration. For this I added an aggreement in the admin panel at "Sales > Billing Agreements" and selected "On customer registration" at the "Display on" menu.

While checkout, this works fine.

Using the user registration page, no agreements show up and the registration returns "Agreements not confirmed." ("Bedingungen wurden nicht bestätigt.").

From the translation table, I can say that the error message comes from Firegento. So I suspect that a few lines of code containing the agreements are just missing. But which?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

The "Studioforty9_Recaptcha" plugin overrides the form.additional.info block and thus deletes, the agreements. Eventhough Recaptcha was disabled for creating accounts.

More about this: https://github.com/firegento/firegento-magesetup/issues/330